# я хочу запустить bat файл при помощи subprocess.call(). Как сделать так, что бы не появлялась консоль?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess

Здравствуйте, возможно ли вызывать подпроцессы так, чтобы они вызывались неявно? Допустим, я хочу запустить bat файл при помощи subprocess.call(). Как сделать так, что бы не появлялась консоль?

Comment: subprocess.call(shell=False или True)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [How do I hide the console when I use os.system() or subprocess.call()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7006238/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Используя `STARTUPINFO` (из [ответа @eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7006424/4279)):

```
import subprocess

startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
#startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE # default
subprocess.check_call('batch.bat', startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

Более [краткое решение это `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7509054/4279):

```
subprocess.check_call('batch.bat', shell=True)
```

Это решение [конфигурирует STARTUPINFO за вас](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/122e88a8354e3f75aeaf6211232dac88ac296d54/Lib/subprocess.py#L982-L984), но у него могут быть побочные эффекты. К примеру, может быть [необходимо экранировать мета-символы, понимаемые `cmd.exe`, в передаваемой команде](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867015/4279), также [поиск исполняемого файла по другому алгоритму может происходить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25167402/4279). `shell=True` может быть необходимо для [*внутренних команд*, таких как ASSOC](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html).

Чтобы скрыть консоль для самого Питон-скрипта, достаточно использовать `.pyw` расширение — в этом случае запускается `pythonw.exe` вместо `python.exe`. См. [pythonw.exe or python.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9705982/4279)