# При выполнении ping скрыть окно командной строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Как при выполнении ping через subprocess скрыть окно командной строки?
Пример:

```
subprocess.call(["ping", "-n", "4", google_dns], stdout=False)
```

Comment: ответ найден, нужно добавить shell=True

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [я хочу запустить bat файл при помощи subprocess.call(). Как сделать так, что бы не появлялась консоль?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679594/%d1%8f-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-bat-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-subprocess-call-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так окно не появляется

```
subprocess.call("ping -n 1 google.com", stdout=False, shell=True)
```